# Создание страницы с разным содержимым

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

необходимо чтобы при загрузки данных генерировалась страница от данных бд

---

Пример 1

```
{
[-Заголовок;]
[-блок текста;]
[-блок с видео;]
[-блок с музыкой;]
}
```

---

Пример 2

```
{
[-Заголовок;]
[-блок текста;]
[- блок с картинкой]
[-блок текста;]
[- блок галерея]
[-блок текста;]
}
```

---

И каждый раз содержимое может быть разное, через стандартные шаблоны такое не сделаешь.
Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: я добавил ответ, если он вам подходит, пожалуйста отметьте его как правильный, если нет то опишите причину почему, я постараюсь дать наиболее подходящий под ваш случай ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ реализовать это, сделать на основе маркдауна и в базе данных это просто хранить, картинки разумеется в файлах.

Посмотрите на возможности markdown-it:

https://markdown-it.github.io/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я решил задачу через switch case. в базе данных сохраняю код элемента и содержимое этих элементов. и когда необходимо отобразить содержимое страницы коды перебираются и добавляются если нужны